# Chromium 88 data leaking in kiosk mode

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

I am using Chromium 88 in kiosk mode connected cellular. Chromium is running the site as `http://localhost` with occasional data push from server. Even when a static page is on there is a constant data exchange around 470 bytes per second which is 1MB per hour. Since I am on a cellular with $0.10 per MB this adds up. Is there any way to completely stop chromium in sending any data when idle? Below are the command line inputs I've already tried but I am still not able to stop the data leak. Any thoughts on how to completely stop chromium sending data will be good. I cannot completely work offline mode, because I need to send some data from server once a day to keep it refreshed.

Any pointer will be helpul.

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
--disable-sync
--data-reduction-proxy-lo-fi
--enable-data-reduction-proxy-savings-promo
--disable-background-networking
--disable-component-update
--dns-prefetch-disable
--disable-plugins
--no-pings
--disable-background-mode
--disable-translate
--disable-session-crashed-bubble
--noerrdialogs
--disable-infobars
--kiosk http://localhost
```

Comment: Without identifying the source of the network it is not possible to answer anything. You can use Fiddle or a similar program to listen to the network.

Comment: I simply open chrome with google.com as home page and watch it over nethogs. It shows a constant send and receive of 0.047 kb/sec. I don't have my localhost open.

Comment: Your question states Chromium is running "localhost"; your comment says "chrome with google.com […]. I don't have my localhost open". Which one is it?

Comment: Do you see anything in the network tab of the devtools? Could be websocket traffic from the website

Comment: Thanks for all your comments/feedback. Network tab does not show any traffic. It is idle after the last push from server.

Comment: Both "localhost" and "www.google.com" has the same result of 0.0147 kb/sec constant.

Comment: I think first you need to find out what the data is which is being sent. Can you run wireshark and record network traffic, then analyse it? Once you know what the traffic is, you will be able to know where to disable it. Another option would be blocking all network traffic of Chrome, but that would defeat the purpose of a browser …

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Documenting answer for others. chromium-browser contains google services which starts automatically and connect to account.google.com, *.googleapis.com, safebrowsing.googleapis.com and many others which slowly leaks data around 1 mb per hour. This is not a big deal if connected to WiFi but is an issue when connected to cellular with data only plan. So I removed chromium-browser and added ungoogled-chromium https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium which strips out all google services. They have the latest chromium version and it works exactly the same without google services.

I personally think if anyone using raspberry pi chromium without google services should install this.